# CSS backdrop-filter blur not blurring at the edges correctly on Windows (works on macOS)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-platform, css-filters

The CSS property `backdrop-filter: blur` is causing some issues for me on Windows **(screenshots below)**. At the edges of the filtered area, it doesn't seem to blur all the way to the edge of the container. It appears to almost blur out towards the edges. On macOS it works perfectly as expected. It is particularly noticeable at high blur values (e.g. 40px). Browser used is Chrome.

I've tried scaling the blurred area up with negative margins and scaling the width and height up of the underlying image, and then masking with a smaller container with no luck. I've also tried z-indexes, transform3d amongst others with no luck.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can make this property work correctly on Windows like it does on macOS?

```css
.modal {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 920px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(40px);
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  background-image: url('https://41.media.tumblr.com/efd15be8d41b12a7b0ef17fba27c3e20/tumblr_mqqy59HMaf1qzattso1_1280.jpg');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's a codepen https://codepen.io/romiem/pen/BaWgVNJ

#### macOS (correct behaviour)

[image]

#### Windows (incorrect behaviour)

[image]

Comment: Seems fixed on Win 10 Chrome 98

Comment: Same problem, not fixed. Windows 11, Chrome 110, Hardware Acceleration enabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After over (I think) a year of also having this issue, I have finally figured out the problem:

You have your Chrome set to not use hardware acceleration when available. As soon as I re-enabled that it did the trick, and now my blurs are beautiful!

In Chrome://settings turn on "Use hardware acceleration when available" toggle:

[image: Turning on "Use hardware acceleration when available" toggle in Chrome://Settings]

Comment: Had the same problem with hardware acceleration already on, but was fixed after I turned it off, then back on again with a browser restart in between both actions.